# VS2010 Coded UI Test - Test builder unable to map two checkboxes with same text

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webforms, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create a coded UI test (with VS2010 Ultimate) for a simple web form page with two checkboxes and a submit hyperlink. The checkboxes have the same text label; "I Agree".

- Using the coded UI test builder to record actions, only one checkbox is captured because both checkboxes have the same text / same UIMap Name.
- Using the crosshair tool to select the second checkbox, it replaces the previous checkbox instance because they have the same text / same UIMap Name.

When the test is run, the first checkbox is checked, the second is not, and the hyperlink is clicked to submitted the form (failing validation).

How can I add the second checkbox to the test map and differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no unique properties on the checkboxes themselves, specify the parent object of each checkbox to differentiate them.

Example:
For

```
<div id="box1Parent">
    <input label="I Agree"/>
</div>
<div id=box2Parent">
    <input label="I Agree"/>
</div>
```

You would define the object like this:

```
public HtmlCheckBox AgreementBox1()
{
    HtmlDiv parent = new HtmlDiv(browser);
    parent.SearchProperties["id"] = "box1Parent";
    HtmlCheckBox target = new HtmlCheckBox(parent);
    target.SearchProperties["label"] = "I Agree";
    return target;
}
```

Then, do the same for the second box, but point the parent to `box2Parent`.  This would be your code in the non-designer section of the .uitest class.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. Try to find out unique property of object like id, name.
2. Try to find out parent control/container of checkbox, then use {TAB} or {UP}/{DOWN} keys.
3. Use {TAB} key of keyboard. find out previous control -> click on that control -> use {TAB} from that control to get focus on checkbox control and use {UP}/{DOWN} arrow key to navigate.
4. Find out text of document and click on first or second occurrence of that as per your need.
   Code to find out document Text,

   ```
       public string GetCurrentPageVisibleTexts()
       {
           var window = this.UIMap.<WindowObject>
           UITestControlCollection c = window.GetChildren();
           var pgContent = (string)c[0].GetProperty("OuterHtml");
           var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
           document.LoadHtml(pgContent);

           // We don't want these in our result
           var exclusionText = new string[] { "<!--", "<![CDATA", "function()", "</form>" };

           var visibleTexts = new List<string>();
           //var nodes = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => !d.Name.ToLower().Equals("span"));
           foreach (var elem in document.DocumentNode.Descendants())
           {
               // Foreach element iterate its path back till root 
               // and look for "display: none" attribute in each one of its parent node
               // to verify whether that element or any of its parent are marked as hidden
               var tempElem = elem;

               while (tempElem.ParentNode != null)
               {
                   if (tempElem.Attributes["style"] != null)
                   {
                       // if hidden attribute found then break.
                       if (tempElem.Attributes["style"].Value.ToLower().Contains("display: none")) break;
                   }
                   tempElem = tempElem.ParentNode;
               }

               // If iteration reached to head and element is found clean of hidden property then proceed with text extraction.                    
               if (tempElem.ParentNode == null)
               {
                   if (!exclusionText.Any(e => elem.InnerText.Contains(e))
                   && (!elem.InnerText.Trim().IsNullOrEmpty())
                   && (!elem.HasChildNodes))
                   {
                       visibleTexts.Add(elem.InnerText);
                   }
               }
           } // Foreach close

           var completeText = string.Join(" ", visibleTexts).Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
           return Regex.Replace(completeText, @"\s+", " ");
       }
   ```